# Web Performance - How does Github make their "character images"?

Tags: css, image, performance, web, character

I've noticed all of the small images on Github are actually characters. For this example I'll use the small person image that is used when you assign someone to an issue. If you mouse over the small person image, your cursor changes to the text cursor. If you inspect element, you'll find that the styling of the span has  `content: ""` . I disabled that line, and the image disappeared. It looks like their small images are all "characters". I imagine this is a factor to how fast their website is considering they don't have to load these assets.

How do they create these "character images"?

Comment: I didn't visit the page yet ... but I guess is a font ?

Comment: They use a custom image font called octicons https://github.com/github/octicons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a font.  You can find a very popular example of an "Icon Font" here, at [FontAwesome](http://fontawesome.io/)

Fonts have been used as a replacement for sprites and other methods for compressing icon images for a while these days, and generally offer improved performance at the expense of leaving outdated browsers out of the fun.  For example, IE <=6 do not support WebFonts, and therefore nothing will appear on those browsers.

However, we're at the point where IE 6 and lower aren't really an everyday concern for *most* web developers.  Which is real good news, and makes font icons a plausible alternative to maintaining a large image library for icons.